# trying to position the border related to height

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to position the border with in height range i mean the border will be positioned in same height where key number  reports and instructor reports are started

the diagram is like this [image]

and the code for positioning

```
                <table>
                    <tr style="padding-top:20px: height:18px">
                    <div style="height:03px;width:400px">
                        <td style="width:50%;position:relative;top:10px;bottom:10px;padding-right:8px; padding-top:20px">
                            <b>Key Numbers Report</b><br />
                         <div style=" padding-top:6px;margin-top:07px;text-align:left">                              
                           Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here.
                            Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here.
                            Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here.
                            </div>
                            <a style="float:left;color:#77F;font-size:18px;margin-top:10px" href="./?s=1">View Report</a>
                        </td>

                        <td style="padding-left:25px;position:relative;top:19px;left:10px;border-left:1px #AAA solid;height:10px; padding-top:18px;padding-right:8px">
                            <b>Instructors Report</b><br />
                            <div style ="padding-top:6px;margin-top:07px;text-align:left">
                            Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here.
                            Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here.
                            Text about the information 
                            displayed in this report and what 
                            they can ﬁnd out here
                            </div>
                            <a style="float:left;color:#77F;font-size:18px;margin-top:10px " href="./?s=2">View Report</a>
                        </td>
                        </div>
                    <tr>
                </table>
```

can any one pls help on this

Comment: the border height   is starting from same height as like key numbers report and instructor report title position..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
        <table>
            <tr style="padding-top:20px: height:18px">
            <div style="height:03px;width:400px; margin-top: 20px;">
                <td style="width:50%;position:relative;top:10px;bottom:10px;padding-right:8px; padding-top:0px;">
                    <b>Key Numbers Report</b><br />
                 <div style=" padding-top:6px;margin-top:07px;text-align:left">                              
                   Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here.
                    Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here.
                    Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here.
                    </div>
                    <a style="float:left;color:#77F;font-size:18px;margin-top:10px" href="./?s=1">View Report</a>
                </td>

                <td style="padding-left:25px;position:relative;top:19px;left:10px;border-left:1px #AAA solid;height:10px; padding-top:0px;padding-right:8px">
                    <b>Instructors Report</b><br />
                    <div style ="padding-top:6px;margin-top:07px;text-align:left">
                    Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here.
                    Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here.
                    Text about the information 
                    displayed in this report and what 
                    they can ﬁnd out here
                    </div>
                    <a style="float:left;color:#77F;font-size:18px;margin-top:10px " href="./?s=2">View Report</a>
                </td>
                </div>
            <tr>
        </table>
```

I removed the `padding-top` from your `<td>`s and added `margin-top` on your `<div>` instead.

I have to tell you though, that your html-code is not valid, you are not allowed to have a `<div>` in a `<tr>` before your `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but if the problem is the gap between the top border and the divider, then it's probably because you have a lot of padding and margins in there. Play around with those and see if anything changes.

Also is there a reason you're wrapping the two TDs in a DIV? That just seems like you're adding more trouble for yourself.